# Is there a microcontroller that can output hdmi?

Tags: electronics

Pretty simple question. Is there a microcontroller that can output hdmi? If not, what microcontrollers can output any type of video?

Comment: A Raspberry Pi can output HDMI. A Arduino Uno can output some kind of minimal VGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are looking for. There are lots o chips made to control and process hdmi frames. However, as Jot said, the arduino is not suitable for this. The arduino can output basic VGA, but it does not have enough "horsepower" to play with HDMI. The best and cheapest solution is to use a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Arduino does have a board that can do HDMI (the [MKR Vidor 4000](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/mkr-vidor-4000)), though it's cheating a bit by doing it on a FPGA rather than on the microcontroller itself.

Answer (score 0):

RP2040 can output DVI which HDMI monitors can render.